# How do I find the version of the Exchange mail server I'm connected to?

Tags: exchange, email-server

How do I find out if my corporate email account is hosted on a Exchange 2003 server versus Exchange 2007?

Comment: ask your admin might be a simple solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your workstation hold the CTRL key, right click the Outlook icon in the Notification Tray, select the Connection status item from the context menu, look for the Mail item in the Type column, scroll to the right and look at the version. That is the Exchange Server build number for the server where your mailbox is.

Answer (score 1):

Telnet to it, (telnet exchange.server.com 110 from the command line) and check the banner it returns.

It will look like:

+OK Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 POP3 server version 6.5.7638.1 (exch01.exchange.com) ready.

Here is a link to [the exchange build information page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158530). Match the number in the banner to the number on the page, and that will tell you which version of exchange the server is running.

Edit: Port 25 gives ambiguous results. Changed post to reflect port 110, which is friendlier.

@Jim: Absolutely correct. If you have a front end server, you're not going to get that information this way. You're going to have to query it separately.

Comment: actually it depends on which server you connect to, suppose the frontend server (CAS in 2007 terms) is 2007 but the mailbox server is 2003?

Comment: Good admins will change that message to something more generic. Our company server replies with `+OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.`

Answer (score 0):

or the Email Services Cluster as well, so it could be confusing sometimes., however i use this:

> [PS] C:>Get-ExchangeServer | fl name, edition, admindisplayversion